# How do I change the background color of the selected items in a multiple select box?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a regular html select field.  When a user selects an item from the list, it is added to a multiple select field and marked as selected.  If the user clicks on one of the items in the multiple select field it is removed.  What I want to do is override the default colors of the multiple select field so that selected items have a black background.

I tried using css and the option[selected] tag but that doesn't seem to work.  I can easily change the background color of the select box but not the individually selected items.  What do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Only some browsers have support for the [selected] rule, you can simulate the behavior  using some plugin like [this combobox plugin](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm)